# Evaluate Postfix expression using a tree in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, stack, expression-trees

I am supposed to evaluate a postfix expression using an expression tree.
Got an error while compiling the program

> "The method getElement() is undefined for the type ExpressionTree.Node"

Does getElement doesn't work for stack class?
If not what should I use to get the elements in the stack?

```
import java.util.Stack;
public class ExpressionTree 
{
    Node root;

    // Node sub-class
    public class Node 
    {
        private String key; // key
        private Node left; // links to subtrees
        private Node right;

        public Node(String key)
        {
            this.key = key;
        }
    }

    // constructor to build a tree with postFix expression
    public ExpressionTree(String postFixExpression)
    {
        Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();
        String[] tokens = postFixExpression.split(" ");
        for (String token: tokens) 
        {
            if (isOperator(token))
            {
                Node right = stack.pop();
                Node left = stack.pop();
                Node node = new Node(token);
                node.left = left;
                node.right = right;
                stack.push(node);
            }
            else
            {
                stack.push(new Node(token));
            }
        }
        root = stack.pop();
    }

    private boolean isOperator(String token)
    {
        boolean result = false;
        switch(token) 
        {
            case "+":
            case "-":
            case "*":
            case "/":
                result = true;
                break;
            default:
                result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * @return result of the expression
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public double evaluate() throws Exception
    {
        if (root==null)
            result = 0;
        else
        {
            temp = (ExpressionTreeOp)root.getElement();

            if (temp.isOperator())
            {
                operand1 = evaluateNode(root.getLeft());
                operand2 = evaluateNode(root.getRight());
                if (operator == '+')
            result = operand1 + operand2;

        else if (operator == '-')
            result = operand1 - operand2;
        else if (operator == '*')
            result = operand1 * operand2;
        else 
            result = operand1 / operand2;
            }
            else
                result = temp.getValue();
        }

        return result;

    }

}
```

Comment: Please, make sure that your code is intended properly. Your question was [already edited once](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46768185/revisions), check the edit and try to make your code easier to read.

Comment: You probably want to replace `root.getElement()` with `root.getKey()`

Answer (score 1):

```
root.getElement();
```

`root` here is an object of class `Node`. A compilation error occurs because this class doesn't have a method called `getElement`:

```
// Node sub-class
public class Node 
{
    private String key; // key
    private Node left; // links to subtrees
    private Node right;

    public Node(String key)
    {
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

> Does getElement doesn't work for stack class?

There is no `stack` class in your sample code. To make it clear, Java doesn't create methods automatically, you'll need to inherit a method from some existing class or to implement it yourself.

> If not what should I use to get the elements in the stack?

I guess you'll have to implement this method yourself.

```
Node getElement() {
    //something
}
```

Or use an actual [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) implementation somewhere. This interface provides `peek` and `pop` methods to access the head element of the stack.

Answer (score 1):

There is no getElement() method in either Stack or Vector class in java

Methods of Stack.java class

```
push
pop
peek
empty
search
```

Methods of Vector.java class

```
add
addAll
get
elementAt
firstElement
lastElement
setElementAt
removeElementAt
...........
```